# HDMI not working on Ubuntu 18.04 Acer Swifft 1

Tags: hdmi, acer

I have been running Ubuntu 18 on an Acer Swift 1, but the HDMI port does not work.

If I run `xrandr`, I get

```
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```